# Is there an NDSolve`ProcessEquations analog for NIntegrate?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, numerical-integration

`NDSolve` has an interface for repeatedly solving an equation with different initial conditions without having to analyze the equation and set up the solving algorithm each time. This can improve performance dramatically. For example,

```
nd = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y'[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 1}, {y}, t]    
(* NDSolve`StateData[<0.>] *)

solve[y0_] := Module[{}, nd = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[nd, y[0] == y0]; 
                           NDSolve`Iterate[nd, 1]; NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[nd]]

Timing[NDSolve[{y'[t] == -y[t], y[0] == #}, y, {t, 0, 1}]&/@Range[0.001, 1, 0.001]]//First
(* 0.527396 *)

Timing[solve /@ Range[0.001, 1, 0.001]] // First
(* 0.250309 *)
```

Is there an analogous interface to `NIntegrate` that would allow me to process the integral once, then do integrations using the same integration method (as chosen by `NIntegrate`) repeatedly using different constants in the integrand and/or different limits of integration?

Comment: This is very cool. I need to add this to one of the answers I put up yesterday. The second part inherently requires symbolic integration.

Comment: Just a side note: in and after _v9_, one can achieve the same performance as `solve` with `ParametricNDSolveValue`: `pa = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == -y[t], y[0] == a}, y, {t, 0, 1}, a];
pa /@ Range[0.001, 1, 0.001]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NIntegrate` performs a certain symbolic processing of the integrand to detect discontinuities, singularities, to determine the method to choose and so on.

If you know the integrand pretty well, the way to reduce the overhead is to set the method explicitly, set its `SymbolicProcessing` suboption to 0 (to allow to time spent on the preprocessing), and to add points of discontinuities to the path explicitly.

This can make a significant difference in timing:

```
In[66]:= Do[
  NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{x^2, x <= 1}}, 1/1 + x], {x, 0, 1, 2}, 
   Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", 
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {10^3}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[66]= {1.542154, Null}

In[67]:= Do[
  NIntegrate[
   Piecewise[{{x^2, x <= 1}}, 1/1 + x], {x, 0, 
    2}], {10^3}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[67]= {15.063506, Null}
```

Comment: As there haven't been any other answers to the contrary, I shall conclude that the answer is "no".

Comment: @jXB Yes, to the best of my knowledge, the answer is "no".