# Solving the Euler-Lagrange equation with NDSolve`ProcessEquations

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I would like to compute the shortest distance between a number on pairs of points on a 2-dimensional Riemanniann statistical manifold (Negative Binomial distributions manifold, equipped with the Rao's metrics).

This is sometimes VERY long, because I suspect there is a cut point on the geodesic (at least in a numerical sense, say). So, I thought it was possible to save much time by using `NDSolveProcessEquations` coupled with `NDSolveReinitialize`.

Here are the Christoffel symbols:

```
Subscript[Γ, ϕ, ϕϕ][ϕ_, μ_] := 
  -((μ*(μ + 2*ϕ) + ϕ^2*(μ + ϕ) 
     ((-(ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ)*(μ + (μ + ϕ)*Log[ϕ/(μ + ϕ)])*PolyGamma[1, ϕ] - 
       (μ + ϕ)*(-1 + (ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ)*PolyGamma[2, ϕ]))/ 
          (2*ϕ*(μ + ϕ)*(μ + ϕ*(μ + ϕ)*(-1 + (ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ)*PolyGamma[1, ϕ]))); 
Subscript[Γ, ϕ, ϕμ][ϕ_, μ_] := 
  -((ϕ*(-1 + ϕ*(ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ*(μ + ϕ)*PolyGamma[1, ϕ])) /
    (2*(μ + ϕ)*(μ + ϕ*(μ + ϕ)*(-1 + (ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ)*PolyGamma[1, ϕ]))); 
Subscript[Γ, ϕ, μμ][ϕ_, μ_] := 
  ϕ/(2*(μ + ϕ)*(μ + ϕ*(μ + ϕ)*(-1 + (ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ)*PolyGamma[1, ϕ])); 
Subscript[Γ, μ, ϕϕ][ϕ_, μ_] := 
  (1/2)*μ*(1/(μ*ϕ + ϕ^2) - (ϕ/(μ + ϕ))^ϕ*PolyGamma[1, ϕ]); 
Subscript[Γ, μ, ϕμ][ϕ_, μ_] := μ/(2*ϕ*(μ + ϕ)); 
Subscript[Γ, μ, μμ][ϕ_, μ_] := -((2*μ + ϕ)/(2*μ*(μ + ϕ)));
```

Here is  the Euler-Lagrange equation, depending on the Christoffel symbols (`Chif` is the Precision):

```
GeodE[{u_, v_}, t_, a_, b_] := 
  SetPrecision[
    {Derivative[2][u][t] == 
       -(Subscript[Γ, ϕ, ϕϕ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]^2 + 
          2*Subscript[Γ, ϕ, ϕμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]*
            Derivative[1][v][t] + 
          Subscript[Γ, ϕ, μμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][v][t]^2), 
     Derivative[2][v][t] == 
       -(Subscript[Γ, μ, ϕϕ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]^2 + 
         2*Subscript[Γ, μ, ϕμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]*
           Derivative[1][v][t] + 
         Subscript[Γ, μ, μμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][v][t]^2), 
     {u[0], v[0]} == a, {u[1], v[1]} == b}, 
    Chif];
```

Consider a pair of points such that the equation above can be quickly solved by `NDSolve`.

```
{Easy4a, Easy4b} = {{0.0317527, 0.44814}, {1.46715, 9.50924}};
```

The geodesic can be easily found from

```
{A, B} = {Easy4a, Easy4b};
solGlob =
  TimeConstrained[
    NDSolve[GeodE[{ϕ, μ}, t, A, B], {ϕ, μ}, {t, 0,1}, WorkingPrecision -> Chif], 
    240, "Pas fini"];
```

To determine geodesics between other pair of points, I defined alternatively (as in the documentation of "Components and Data Structures")

```
 EuLa = 
   First[
     NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
       {Derivative[2][u][t] == 
          -(Subscript[Γ, ϕ, ϕϕ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]^2 + 
          2*Subscript[Γ, ϕ, ϕμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]*Derivative[1][v][t] + 
          Subscript[Γ, ϕ, μμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][v][t]^2), 
        Derivative[2][v][t] == 
          -(Subscript[Γ, μ, ϕϕ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]^2 +  
          2*Subscript[Γ, μ, ϕμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]*Derivative[1][v][t] + 
          Subscript[Γ, μ, μμ][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][v][t]^2), 
        {u[0], v[0]} == {A[[1]], A[[2]]}, 
        {u[1], v[1]} == {B[[1]], B[[2]]}}, 
       {u, v}, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

It seems that there is no problem here. Then I tried to find another geodesic, linking two other points:

```
Centre = {0.7767`, 11.207780999999999`};
TestC = {0.7767`, 87.26795000000001`};
B = TestC;
A = Centre;
solBis = NDSolve`Reinitialize[EuLa, {u[0], v[0]} == A, {u[1], v[1]} == B];
```

I corrected "Eula", but there is still an error:

```
NDSolve`Reinitialize::ndcinit: Initial conditions should be specified at a single point.
```

I'm using `NDSolve` (and the "components and data structure" possibilities) for the first time, and I can't see where the problem is. Is the formuation of EuLa ill-written?

Is it impossible?

Yes, it seems. I have to solve some "à la Dirichlet" problem:

```
{A, B} = {Easy4a, Easy4b};
EuLa = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{Derivative[2][u][t] == -(Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \[Phi], \[Phi]\[Phi]][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]^2 + 
    2*Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \[Phi], \[Phi]\[Mu]][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]*Derivative[1][v][t] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \[Phi], \[Mu]\[Mu]][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][v][t]^2), 
 Derivative[2][v][t] == -(Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \[Mu], \[Phi]\[Phi]][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]^2 + 2*Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \[Mu], \[Phi]\[Mu]][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][u][t]*
     Derivative[1][v][t] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \[Mu], \[Mu]\[Mu]][u[t], v[t]]*Derivative[1][v][t]^2), {u[0], v[0]} == {A[[1]], A[[2]]}, 
 {u[1], v[1]} == {B[[1]], B[[2]]}}, {u, v}, t]]
NDSolve`Iterate[EuLa, 0]
NDSolve`Iterate[EuLa, 1]
initial = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[EuLa];
Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Red, Point[A]}], Graphics[{PointSize[0.07], GrayLevel[0.6], Point[B]}],
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{u[t], v[t]} /. initial], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]

slope = {Derivative[1][u][0], Derivative[1][v][0]} /. initial
```

Thanks to "slope", we obtain exactly the same solution by solving with NDSolve`Reinitialize the equivalent à la Cauchy problem:

```
new1 = First[NDSolve`Reinitialize[EuLa, {{u[0], v[0]} == A, {Derivative[1][u][0], Derivative[1][v][0]} == slope}]]
NDSolve`Iterate[new1, 0]
NDSolve`Iterate[new1, 1]
sol1 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[new1]
Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Red, Point[A]}], Graphics[{PointSize[0.07], GrayLevel[0.6], Point[B]}],` ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{u[t], v[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]`
```

The Cauchy boundary condition can be changed, giving rise to another valid solution:

```
{A, B} = {TestC, Centre}
new2 = First[NDSolve`Reinitialize[EuLa, {{u[0], v[0]} == A, {Derivative[1][u][0], Derivative[1][v][0]} == B}]]
NDSolve`Iterate[new2, 0]
NDSolve`Iterate[new2, 1]
sol2 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[new2]
Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Red, Point[A]}],
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{u[t], v[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, 1},
PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

It could be interesting to compute the exponential map, but it seems impossible to solve my Dirichlet problem under these conditions:

```
new3 = First[NDSolve`Reinitialize[EuLa, {{u[0], v[0]} == A, {u[1], v[1]} == B}]]
NDSolve`Iterate[new3, 0]
NDSolve`Iterate[new3, 1]
sol3 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[new3]
NDSolve`Reinitialize::ndcinit: Initial conditions should be specified at a single point.
```

Am I right?

Claude

Comment: Please show us the code text of the example, not pictures of part of it. If you don't know how to, check this post: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871

Comment: A first error that I can see is that you are assigning your equations to a variable named `EuLa`, but when you want to solve them you call to `Eula`.

Comment: Value of `Chif` is missing, and the part defining `solGlob` causes `infy` warning and fails, at least in v9.0.1. Please check the sample carefully before posting it here. Then, have you tried `ParametricNDSolve`?

Comment: Chif is the precision (MachinePrecision, or another reasonable number). I use version 11.0.1, and I can plot solGlob without any problem (what is infy?). I also tried ParametricNDSolve ; the result was the same (excepted for pairs of very distant points, where the geodesic is hard to obtain), but the computation was much lengthy. Thus, I chose NDSolve, even if ParametricNDSolve seemed to work better in few pathological situations.

Comment: Just tested on Cloud, OK, seems that `NDSolve` is improved in v11. In v9.0.1 I only got `Power::infy` warning, and even if I manually set up `"Shooting"` method, I need to give a very good initial guess and manually set up `"ImplicitSolver"` as `Method -> {"Shooting", 
  "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
   With[{b = 0}, {{\[Phi][b], \[Mu][b]} == 
      Rationalize[A, 0], {Derivative[1][\[Phi]][b], Derivative[1][\[Mu]][b]} == 
      Rationalize[{0.22659514943257, 4.5093449250158}, 0]}], 
  "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}`. Then, back to your question…

Comment: …1. `solBis` still contains simple mistake, you missed a pair of braces. 2. Though `ndcinit` doesn't own a document page, I think the following explanation is quite clear. "Initial conditions should be specified at a single point." This suggests ``NDSolve`Reinitialize`` can only be used for reinitializing a initial problem i.e. all the constraint condition should be given at "a single point" e.g. `{u[0], v[0]} == A, {u'[0], v'[0]} == 0` 3. I don't think ``NDSolve`Reinitialize`` approach will be faster than `ParametricNDSolve` approach, because the latter is probably a "shell" of the former…

Comment: …Let's check with the example [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192/1871). The timing of `solve /@ Range[0.001, 1, 0.001]` in my PC is `0.247410`, and `pa = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == -y[t], y[0] == a}, y, {t, 0, 1}, a];
pa /@ Range[0.001, 1, 0.001]; // AbsoluteTiming` outputs `{0.247407, Null}`. Almost the same! (You can test it yourself. ) 【End of comment】